# Listbox populating unioning 2 queries (SQL; Access)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to populate my listbox in MS Access by data which comes from 2 sets of data:

- Required operations (Model_Operation_ID - unique)
- Operations marked manually by user (Model_Operation_ID - unique)

For instance a selected item has 4 `Model_Operation_ID`s:

```
1405
1298
1142
745
```

And user adds 2 additional `Model_Operation_ID`s:

```
542
187
```

I want to populate the 6 of them into my listbox in the form.

Can you please point me in right direction when it comes down to the usual way on how people do this?

Comment: Are these records in two separate tables or are they records in the same table with different attributes? What have you already tried?

Comment: probably thinking along the same lines as jhTuppeny, all this data should be in the same table, making this relatively simple to accomplish. Is there a reason they are held in two separate tables?

Comment: They are in 2 separeted tables - reason being is that the first table is for "ALWAYS do these operations" and the second one is "UNEXPECTED operations". In the end they concat together into 1 table based on the Order_Id.

Answer (score 1):

Use a union query:

Example:

```
Select Model_Operation_ID as MyID From SomeTableOrQuery
Union All
Select Model_Operation_ID as MyID From SomeOtherTableOrQuery
```